How to show bars above lines' area of ​style gradient effect in charts?
I need to achieve this result visually speaking

So far, i have been able to go this far. Is it possible to make the gradient areaStyle show behind the bars ?
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
   "xAxis":{
      "type":"time",
   },
   "yAxis":{
      "type":"value"
   },
   "tooltip":{
      "show":true,
      "trigger":"axis"
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "name":"Test",
         "type":"line",
         "silent":true,
         "animation":false,
         "areaStyle":{
            "opacity":0.1,
         },
         "lineStyle":{
            "width":1
         },
         "data":[
            [
               1620993840000,
               47.6
            ],
            [
               1620993900000,
               50.8
            ],
            [
               1620993960000,
               52.3
            ],
         ],
         "emphasis":{
            "scale":false,
            "focus":"none"
         }
      }
   ],
};

myChart.setOption(option);

I tried a few things with the zlevel property but i could only bring the bars to front if the whole line series is behind (line and dots itself).
I want to keep the line series and dots in front. Only the gradient effect should be behind. Is it possible ?
Thank you.

Just to be clear, you want the line to be on the top z-index, then the vertical bars underneath that, and finally the gradient fill of the line chart at the bottom? If so, I doubt that will be possible out of the box. You may be able to manually hack around some CSS to make it work, but it would be very brittle, and would entirely depend on how the chart library renders content.

Yes, that's precisely what i wanted

Best I can think of is to separate the line and the area into two series. This can make things more difficult in other places, like for example the legend, where you need to apply changes to both series on legendselectchanged event. Also you lose the area animation.
Example:
option = {
  ...,
  series: [
    ...,
    {
      name: 'Value',
      type: 'line',
      symbolSize: 15,
      symbol: 'circle',
      smooth: true,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      lineStyle: {
        color: '#18A0FB'
      },
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#18A0FB'
      },
      data: [5299.8, 43865.49, 29282.58, 30024.3, 34324.3]
    },
    {
      name: 'Area',
      type: 'line',
      silent: true,
      tooltip: {show: false},
      areaStyle: {
        opacity: 1,
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: '#4D18A0FB'
          },
          {
            offset: 0.8,
            color: '#18A0FB0D'
          }
        ])
      },
      z: 0,
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'none'
      },
      symbol: 'none',
      smooth: true,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      data: [5299.8, 43865.49, 29282.58, 30024.3, 34324.3]
    },
  ]
};

myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function(params) {
  let opacity = 0;
  if (params.selected.Value) opacity = 1;
  myChart.setOption({series: [{name: 'Area', areaStyle: {opacity: opacity}}]});
});

